# Xcode: Code completion for method parameters

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Currently I learning Swift/SwiftUI and using Xcode. I have some "troubles" with autocompletion

---

**Actual behaviour (example)**

VStack can have 3 parameters [alignment:spacing:content:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onS4E.png)

When I start type "spa" autocompletion shows and when I press Enter/TAB it automatically add all 3 parameters - which is correct

---

**What I want:**

It is possible to somehow add only one ? (In this case spacing). I know I can delete unnecessary parameters or type full length "spacing:" but is there any shortcut for this ?

Thanks for advice

Comment: That will happen when you get the newest Xcode either is beta now or when it is released from beta later in the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new Xcode 14, you can actually do this by:

- if you want to call a VStack with only spacing as a parameter just type "vspa", then a VStack with (spacing:...) will come up. the "spacing" will be in bold format, then you just press enter to fill out everything.
- Or "valign" for VStack with only alignment as a parameter.

For more info and how to do it, you can watch the latest video of Paul Hudson with the below link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2TDGeevDWo